# Android Audio m3u8 Streaming - HOW TO

Tags: android, streaming, m3u8

As the title, how can I stream an m3u8 audio on Android without vitamio? (on Android 2.3+). I've seen that some app can stream my my link http://4metest1-view.4me.it/api/xpublisher/resources/weebopublisher/getContentDescriptor.m3u8?clientId=4metest1&contentId=b55f7d74-cd81-48ce-9390-d9ffd5c49281&channelType=STREAMHTTPIOS&v=4
like VLC or aqua Player, but i cannot setup mMediaPlayer to reproduce it.

Comment: Are you using a streaming service such as Icecast or Shoutcast?

Comment: no, is not a shoutcast, it's just a HLS HTTP streaming, but mediaplayer won't reproduce it. The same server can stream m3u8 with audio and video, and this video stream hasn't any problem in android. This m3u8 Audio only yes :( what can i do?

Comment: In Android 2.3 & 3.0, you have to use httplive:// scheme, in 3.1 use http://. What version of android are you testing in?

Comment: Right now i'm testing on S3 with 4.1.2, S2 with 4.2 and nexus with 4.3. In nexus 4, i have only to pass to mediaplayer the http-m3u8 to reproduce with phone gallery the music. In s2 and s3, the gallery player says "cannot reproduce video". I'm not understanding why.

Comment: Can you pass in source type to make sure it doesn't try video? mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

Comment: Already done, still no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VideoView to play your audio with relaxing music :)

```
myVideoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            myVideoView.setMediaController(mc);                     
            urlStream = "http://4metest1-view.4me.it/api/xpublisher/resources/weebopublisher/getContentDescriptor.m3u8?clientId=4metest1&contentId=b55f7d74-cd81-48ce-9390-d9ffd5c49281&channelType=STREAMHTTPIOS&v=4";
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlStream)); 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your m3u8 is not a true HLS file. It is just a playlist pointer to a single MP3

```
http://4metest1-4me.weebo.it/ios/Dance_of_the_Yao_People_3_JIDMQ7.mp3
```

You can either use media player to stream from the source directly or parse the file m3u8 file in your code to pull out the idividual URL's

```
url url = new URL(" http://4metest1-view.4me.it/api/xpublisher/resources/weebopublisher/getContentDescriptor.m3u8?clientId=4metest1&contentId=b55f7d74-cd81-48ce-9390-d9ffd5c49281&channelType=STREAMHTTPIOS&v=4");

InputStream m3u8 = (InputStream) url.getContent();      
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(M3U8));
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    br.readLine();
}|
readLine(); //this parses the third line of the playlist
br.close();
url = new URL(baseURL.concat(target));
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what i'm looking for. The link is only an example of the url configuration, because i need it for a webradio (NO SHOUTCAST), so i can't findout every single mp3 fragment.

Comment: Okay so you are trying to create and Internet Radio stream? Are you not using a broadcast agent of any type? Just straight playlist Links?

Comment: I am trying to play in my android device an on demand audio stream delivered with HLS protocol.  The problem is not in the m3u8 I've posted: in fact I can play it with IOS devices, VLC and other HLS player like this http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/.  I've noticed that i can play HLS on demand video stream, but it doen't work if the streams is only audio.