# Android streaming from Gopro

Tags: android

I want to display video streaming from a Gopro Hero3 camera in an android activity. I tried using Vitamio library as indicated here [Android Audio m3u8 Streaming - HOW TO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220208/android-audio-m3u8-streaming-how-to) with the standard address used for streaming in VLC http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8 and that didn't work. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://karanbalkar.com/2014/11/tutorial-92-live-streaming-using-vitamio-in-android/ and that worked !

Comment: Do you get the stream in VLC?

Comment: No I got it using vitamio plugin as in the tutorial above.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer to this popular repo for GoPro:

[KonradIT/goprowifihack](https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack)

Note that different GoPro models have different implementation.